# Why does the null-conditional operator change regular property access?

Tags: c#, null-conditional-operator, safe-navigation-operator

I'm confused about how the null-conditional operator cascades with normal property access.  Take these two examples:

```
a?.b.c
(a?.b).c
```

I would expect them to be equivalent: first, the value of `a?.b` is evaluated, then `result.c` is evaluated.  Thus if `a == null`, an exception should be thrown.

However, that only happens in the second expression.  The first expression evaluates to `null`, meaning it's the same as `a?.b?.c`. **Why?**

Comment: This is the safe-navigation-operator.

Comment: Nope, it stops at `?.` if `a` is null.  The second one ends up telling it you definitely want to evaluate `c`.

Comment: @FrankerZ In C# it's called the null conditional operator.

Comment: @FrankerZ The [official docs call it the null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators), which is why I used that term.

Comment: I think this is a case of operator precedence. `(` and `)` ensures what's inside them gets evaluated, then what's outside. Whereas `a?.b.c` simply evaluates from left to right, and stops when `a?` becomes false.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The important part to notice in the docs is _The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. If one operation in a chain of conditional member access and index operation returns null, then the rest of the chain’s execution stops_

Comment: @juharr: Ah, it's written right in the very docs I linked.  Doh!  Please create an answer and I'll accept it _(also, not sure why people are saying it's a matter of operator precedence; it's not, it's a matter of short-circuiting)_

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the first is like `a == null ? null : a.b.c;` where as the second is like `(a == null ? null : a.b).c;`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It is involved in this question. In c# it's both considered the null conditional operator, but several websites consider it as a safe navigation operator as well. See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/) and [here](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/89-net/7016-c-gets-a-new-operator-safe-navigation.html). They are essentially interchangeable, and I think this question directly relates to safe navigation (As one example triggers an exception).

Comment: @juharr Please write an answer and I will accept it. I do not like either of the existing answers.

Answer (score 9):

That's only a matter of operator precedence. Let's go through the cases:

> a?.b.c

1. Evaluate `a` => `null` is returned, nothing else is evaluated given that [the null-conditional operators are short-circuiting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators).

> (a?.b).c

1. Evaluate `a` => `null` is returned
2. Evaluate `((B)null).c` => `NullReferenceException` is thrown

For these cases to be equivalent, you should be comparing

1. `a?.b.c`
2. `(a?.b)?.c`
3. `a?.b?.c` (as you already mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this'll help or not, beyond what Camilo already provided, but here's a brief comparison showing how the logic might look without the null-conditional operator in play.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a;

        a = new A { b = new B { c = 5 } };

        Console.WriteLine(a?.b.c);        // returns 5;
        Console.WriteLine((a?.b).c);      // returns 5;

        a = null;

        Console.WriteLine(a?.b.c ?? -1);  // returns -1;
        Console.WriteLine((a?.b).c);      // throws NullReferenceException


        // Similar to a?.b.c

        if (a != null)
            Console.WriteLine(a.b.c);     // returns 5;
        else
            Console.WriteLine(-1);        // returns -1;


        // Similar to (a?.b).c

        B tmp;
        if (a != null)
            tmp = a.b;
        else
            tmp = null;

        Console.WriteLine(tmp.c);         // returns 5 or throws NullReferenceException
    }
}


public class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```